# How could visually match 2 trees?

Tags: angularjs, tree

I wrote a script that loads data from 2 tables.
Using this script I need to just match corresponding elements in these 2 columns.

I am using angular-ui-tree for managing columns, but can't come up with an idea how to visually and programmatically match corresponding elements between 2 trees?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what is your problem here. I assuming by "matching visually" you do not mean you need some AI API to actually do visual match, so you just want to get objects that are in the same location in the UI tree?

Using `$nodeScope (type: Scope of ui-tree-node)` should give you that information, as the property of $nodeScope is something like  "1.1.1" or "1.1.2" etc. So you can just parse the "parent" node to get all children belonging to same node.

Scope also has a method `isParent(nodeScope)` which can check if a certain node (that calls the method) is a parent of targeted node. Similarly Scope has `isSibling(targetNodeScope)` and `isChild(targetNodeScope)` methods to help you identify the relationships. As a general guide, you just follow the  (array) of nodes in a (nested) loop and pick the elements or objects you need. You can pick the objects from both UI trees at the same time, so they should be from the same node at that point.